# jquery subtraction not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

every thing is working except the subtraction

```
function add_culture(ele)
    {
        total=parseInt($('#total_price').val());
        culture_price=parseInt($('#culture_price').val());

        $('#total_price').val(culture_price);

        obj=$(ele).val();
        var myObject = eval('(' + obj + ')');

        price=parseInt(myObject['price']);
        $('#culture_price').val(price);

        $('#total_price').val(parseInt(total-culture_price));

        $('#total_price').val(total+price);

        count_remaining();

    }
```

i want to know what is the problem .......................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Why are you trying to parseInt the result of subtracting two numbers?

Comment: There's so much wrong with this snippet.

Comment: Also you are setting the same element, `#total_price`, to a new value, right after you set it to the subtracted value, which will overwrite what you just did with the subtraction.

Comment: Try to put comment above every line of code to describe what it does, you will find many answers that way ;)

Comment: You have wrote $(‘#total_price’).val(total+price) after subtraction line. So it’s value will be replaced with addition.

Comment: Try parseInt(total) - parseInt(culture_price)

Comment: without parsing it is still not working ... just the sum is working

Comment: Because you're setting the sum on the same element that you set the subtraction on.  Two people have already pointed this out.  If you set `x = y - z` and then do `x = y + z`, why would you expect x to contain the subtracted value?

Comment: You're overriding the value of `total_price` three times in this script

Comment: @Phiter - that's not very helpful. Why don't you be helpful and explain to the OP what is actually wrong :/

Comment: also `myObject['price']` will give you undefined because myObject is probably number.

Comment: iam working with a select option .. after i change it i want to delete the last value and add the new value ..price is the new value and culture price is the price of the previous item

Answer (score 0):

You're overriding the value of `total_price` three times in your script, try to append just the final calculated value at the end.

You may need to store your calculated total in a separate variable to keep the things clear:

```
function add_culture(ele)
{
    var total = parseInt($('#total_price').val());
    var culture_price = parseInt($('#culture_price').val());
    var obj = $(ele).val();
    var myObject = eval('(' + obj + ')');
    var price = parseInt(myObject['price']);
    var final_total = (total-culture_price)+price;

    $('#culture_price').val(price);
    $('#total_price').val(final_total);

    count_remaining();
}
```

Comment: i want to subtract the price of the previous item and add the price of the new item .. so iam doing two operations sum and subtract

Comment: Yes that what I doing in this line `var final_total = (total-culture_price)+price;` , subtract `culture_price` and add `price`

Answer (score -1):

You have replaced value of total_price in the second line

**Error:**

```
$('#total_price').val(parseInt(total-culture_price));
//$('#total_price').val(total+price); /* Comment this line in your code! */
```

Comment: Those two values are already parsed in the first two lines of the method.  You don't have to parse them there.

Comment: You now have the one the errors in OP code you send substruct and overwrite with addition and redundant parseInt on number.

Comment: You are showing the error, without showing the solution.  That's the same as making a comment pointing out the error.  This isn't an answer.